# How can I preprocess data into tensors

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I'm building a machine learning model in pytorch to find patterns in unstructured data. The data is in the form of files(log files). My question is can anyone tell me or show me a resource that can show me how I can convert this data into tensors or numeric data for the model, I have copied a small amount of the data I have as an example, thank you, this is my first post on stack overflow so I hope I didn't sound to confusing, thank you again for any help.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:100.0) Gecko/100.0 Firefox/100.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:85.0) Gecko/85.0 Firefox/85.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:91.0) Gecko/91.0 Firefox/91.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:92.0) Gecko/92.0 Firefox/92.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:93.0) Gecko/93.0 Firefox/93.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:96.0) Gecko/96.0 Firefox/96.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:97.0) Gecko/97.0 Firefox/97.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:98.0) Gecko/98.0 Firefox/98.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:99.0) Gecko/99.0 Firefox/99.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:100.0) Gecko/100.0 Firefox/100.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:93.0) Gecko/93.0 Firefox/93.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:96.0) Gecko/96.0 Firefox/96.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:97.0) Gecko/97.0 Firefox/97.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:98.0) Gecko/98.0 Firefox/98.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:99.0) Gecko/99.0 Firefox/99.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 12; Mobile; rv:100.0) Gecko/100.0 Firefox/100.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 12; Mobile; rv:85.0) Gecko/85.0 Firefox/85.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 12; Mobile; rv:96.0) Gecko/96.0 Firefox/96.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 12; Mobile; rv:97.0) Gecko/97.0 Firefox/97.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 12; Mobile; rv:98.0) Gecko/98.0 Firefox/98.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 12; Mobile; rv:99.0) Gecko/99.0 Firefox/99.0   
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.2.1; Mobile; rv:68.0) Gecko/68.0 Firefox/68.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.2.2; Tablet; rv:68.0) Gecko/68.0 Firefox/68.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.3; Tablet; rv:43.0) Gecko/43.0 Firefox/43.0  
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 6.0.1; Mobile; rv:99.0) Gecko/99.0 Firefox/99.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:68.0) Gecko/68.0 Firefox/68.0  
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:98.0) Gecko/98.0 Firefox/98.0  
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.0; Mobile; rv:99.0) Gecko/99.0 Firefox/99.0  
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 8.0.0; Mobile; rv:68.0) Gecko/68.0 Firefox/68.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 8.0.0; Mobile; rv:86.0) Gecko/86.0 Firefox/86.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 8.0.0; Mobile; rv:98.0) Gecko/98.0 Firefox/98.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 8.1.0; Mobile; rv:94.0) Gecko/94.0 Firefox/94.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 8.1.0; Mobile; rv:97.0) Gecko/97.0 Firefox/97.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 8.1.0; Mobile; rv:99.0) Gecko/99.0 Firefox/99.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:91.0) Gecko/91.0 Firefox/91.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:94.0) Gecko/94.0 Firefox/94.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:96.0) Gecko/96.0 Firefox/96.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:98.0) Gecko/98.0 Firefox/98.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:99.0) Gecko/99.0 Firefox/99.0    
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Mobile Safari/537.36   
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Mobile Safari/537.36    
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.79 Mobile Safari/537.36    
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Mobile Safari/537.36    
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.88 Mobile Safari/537.36 
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/99.0.4844.88 Mobile DuckDuckGo/5 Safari/537.36    
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10.0; A37) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36 
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10.0; P40 Pro) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML  like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.73 Mobile Safari/537.36
```